# Selenium locator not finding all the urls on amazon

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm using the following code to extract search results from Amazon. Even though there are 22 product URLs, the program picks only 17 of them. It is skipping a few URLs. What could be the reason?

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
Import time

chrome_driver_path = "driver/chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

url = 'https://www.amazon.in/'

driver.get(url)

keyword = 'iphone charger'

search_box = driver.find_element_by_id('twotabsearchtextbox')
search_box.send_keys(keyword)

search_button = driver.find_element_by_id('nav-search-submit-text')
search_button.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(15)
product_link = []


items = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "s-result-item s-asin sg-col-0-of-12 sg-col-16-of-20 sg-col s-widget-spacing-small sg-col-12-of-16")]')))

for item in items:

    link = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[@class="a-link-normal s-underline-text s-underline-link-text s-link-style a-text-normal"]').get_attribute('href')
    print(link)

    product_link.append(link)
    time.sleep(6)

print(len(product_link))

driver.quit()
```

Comment: I see only 22 main cards on the first page

Comment: my mistake, it is infact 22, upon further inspection of the data - the sponsored listing are the ones not being captured even though they also share the same path. @HimanshuPoddar

Comment: SO the issue is resolves or you need answer t get the link for those 22 cards?

Answer (score 0):

you can Press F12, to search this xpath '//div[contains(@class, "s-result-item s-asin sg-col-0-of-12 sg-col-16-of-20 sg-col s-widget-spacing-small sg-col-12-of-16")]', to see how many elements matched, if it is 17, not 30. you need improve the xpath manually.

Comment: it is not 30 but 22 cards, upon further inspection of the data - the sponsored listing are the ones not being captured even though they also share the same path. Any JS tricks of amazon I'm missing?